# How do match source code with build number from nu-get

Tags: asp.net-core

In my project.json I have a reference to 
`"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta6-14192",`

In github https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc I don't know which source is used for this build.

Where do I find this information?

Answer (score 2):

Right now, there's no easy way to get the commit id. But for all the packages that will be released after today noon-ish time (PDT), that will be possible. You will be able to run `dnu sources get <package-name>` and you'll get the sources for that particular package.

To unblock you, I've looked in our internal CI. MVC build 14192 was produced from commit `37f056ce2bd930635fbfa1370b7ccf5752130c7f`